# Removing last characters of NSString until it hits a separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I've got a string that shows the stock amount using "-" as separators.

It's built up like this: `localStock`-`wareHouseStock`-`supplierStock`

Now I want to update the supplierStock at the end of the string, but as you can see in the code below it goes wrong when the original string returns more than a single-space value (such as 20).

Is there a way to remove all characters until the last "-" (or remove characters after the second "-")?

```
NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: p1.colorStock];
                NSLog(@"string1: %@",string1);
                NSString *newString = [string1 substringToIndex:[string1 length]-2];
                NSLog(@"newString: %@",newString);
                NSString *colorStock = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",newString,p2.supplierStock];
                NSLog(@"colorstock: %@",colorStock);
                p1.colorStock = colorStock;
```

**NSLog1**

```
string1: 0-0-0
newString: 0-0
colorstock: 0-0-20
```

**NSLog2**

```
string1: 0-0-20
newString: 0-0-
colorstock: 0-0--20
```

**EDIT:** Got it working thanks to Srikar!

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithString: p1.colorStock];
                NSLog(@"string1: %@",string1);
                NSString  *finalString = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject] withString:p2.supplierStock.stringValue];
                NSLog(@"finalString: %@",finalString);
                p1.colorStock = finalString;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use `componentsSeparatedByString` followed by `lastObject` ?

`NSString *supplierStock = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject];`

The above works if the "stock amount" is always in sets of 3's separated by a "-". Also since you always want supplierStock, `lastObject` is perfect for your needs.

Of course after splitting `string1` with `-` you get a `NSArray` instance and you can access the individual components using `objectAtIndex:index`. So if you want `localStock` you can get  by

`NSString *localStock = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest splitting the string into the 3 parts using `[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]` and then building it back up again:

```
NSArray *components = [p1.colorStock componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
p1.colorStock = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",
    [components objectAtIndex:0],
    [components objectAtIndex:1],
    p2.supplierStock];
```

Answer (score 1):

With a string that looks like

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello-World";
```

you can separate it with the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of the NSString object as

```
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

The `myWords` - array will then contain the two `NSString` objects `Hello` and `World`.

To access the strings:

```
NSString *theHelloString = [myWords objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *theWorldString = [myWords objectAtIndex:1];
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

None of these examples show how to do this if you are unaware of how many of these separator occurrences you're going to have in the original string.

Here's what I believe the correct the correct code should be for dismantling the original string and rebuilding it until you reach the final separator, regardless of how many separators it contains.

```
NSString *seperator = @" ";
NSString *everythingBeforeLastSeperator;

NSArray *stringComponents = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:seperator];

if (stringComponents.count!=0) {

    everythingBeforeLastSeperator = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:0];

    for (int a = 1 ; a < (stringComponents.count - 1) ; a++) {
        everythingBeforeLastSeperator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", everythingBeforeLastSeperator, seperator, [stringComponents objectAtIndex:a]];
    }
}

return everythingBeforeLastSeperator;
```